# How to prevent OpenJPA 2.2.2 add extra cross join for multiple-root query

Tags: openjpa

I have two tables that don't have a defined relation, but I'm still trying to join them together in a single query, using criteria builder API.

This query work as I want it to - synchronizing the rows from both tables:

```
Root<E_Application> root = q.from(E_Application.class);
Root<E_Searcher> root2 = q.from(E_Searcher.class);
q.where(cb.equal(root.get(E_Application_.packageName),
        root2.get(E_Searcher_.packageName)));
q.select(cb.sum(cb.literal(1)));
```

the query that comes out is: `select sum(1) from application t0 cross join application_searcher t1 where (t0.package_name = t1.package_name);`

However, if I add another join:

```
Root<E_Application> root = q.from(E_Application.class);
Root<E_Searcher> root2 = q.from(E_Searcher.class);
Join<E_Application, E_AppState> j1 =
        root.join(E_Application_.publicAppState);
q.where(cb.equal(root.get(E_Application_.packageName),
        root2.get(E_Searcher_.packageName)));
q.select(cb.sum(cb.literal(1)));
```

I get an extra cross join, and end up with a Cartesian product: `SELECT SUM(1) FROM application t0 CROSS JOIN application t1 CROSS JOIN application_search t3 INNER JOIN application_state t2 ON t1.PUBLICAPPSTATE_ID = t2.id WHERE (t0.package_name = t3.package_name)`

Is there any way to prevent this (except for defining the proper relationship between Application and Searcher)? Is this a proper implementation of the spec? It's sort of weird that the resulting query effectively has a root that I didn't explicitly request, and don't have control over...

The database is postgres, if it matters.

P.S. The reason there is no relationship is because these two tables have their PKs the same, and you can't have a PK that is also an entity reference.